An infinite integral convergence problem related to convex functions.
Suppose that $f(x)$ is a convex funtion defined on $[a,+\infty)$, and when $x\to+\infty$, $\frac{f(x)}{x} \to+\infty$. Prove that integrals both $\int_{a}^{+\infty} \sin{f(x)}dx$ and $ \int_{a}^{+\infty} \cos{f(x)}dx$ converge.
If using real analysis, one can ascertain that the convex function $f(x)$  is almost everywhere differentiable and possesses a certain monotonicity, thereby allowing for a solution to the problem through substitution of $f(x)$. However, I wonder if it's possible to resolve this issue using calculus methods. I hope someone can clarify my doubts!

Sorry for the fault and the integration bounds have been revised.

The two integrales cannot converge at the same time since if $\int^\infty F $ converges, necessarily $\lim_\infty F=0$
